# Filter Database values to set string format

Tags: c#

I am trying to filter my database values that matches my condition.

Here is code:

```
con = new SqlConnect();
con.SqlQuery("Select * from DeductionInfo where [IS Percentage] = @yes");
con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yes", "' Yes '");

sdr = con.cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (sdr.Read().ToString() == "Yes")
{
    ii.SubItems[2].Text = string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDouble(ii.SubItems[2].Text.ToString()));
}
else
{
    ii.SubItems[2].Text = string.Format("{0:P0}", Convert.ToDouble(ii.SubItems[2].Text.ToString()));
}

con.cmd.Connection.Close();
```

But the output is not what I want:

[image]

I want the values to be formatted to Dollar sign if the condition is "No" and Percent if the conditions is "Yes". Can I have a help on this? Thanks

Comment: If you work from Visual Studio, then put a breakpoint on the line with `if`. Look what is the value of `sdr.Read().ToString()`. It's obvious that it's never `"Yes"` in your example and this is why you always execute the `else` branch

Comment: I removed the == "Yes" and still it goes to else condition. even if the the condition says No.

Comment: Again check what is the value of `sdr.Read().ToString()`. Is it `"No"`, is it `"Yes"` or is it something else?

Comment: the value is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.

Comment: So obviously it's not a string, you should find a way in some tutorial how to read actual values

Comment: @AlexLarionov I think I made it, is there any chance for you to check if it is right?

Comment: if it actually works, then just update your answer with a working version

Comment: Am I gonna answer my own Question? Is that allowed?

Comment: Why not, it might help other people to answer similar questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my own question. I took it out inside the foreach loop and made a for loop.

```
      con = new SqlConnect();
        con.SqlQuery("Select * from DeductionInfo order by [Deduction Title] ASC");
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(con.cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString() == "Yes")
            {
                lvUserManagement.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = string.Format("{0:P0}", Convert.ToDouble(lvUserManagement.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text.ToString()));
            }
            else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString() == "No")
            {

                lvUserManagement.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDouble(lvUserManagement.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text.ToString()));
            }
        }
        con.cmd.Connection.Close();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBYEl.jpg)